# How can I see which "Date & time" settings are "hidden or managed by your organization" (and where)

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, time, windows-domain, ntp

I am on a domain-joined Laptop which cannot connect to the domain controller except once a month or less, so the system time is off by 10 seconds. I can set it manually, but I'd like it to sync to public NTP servers instead. So some reason, it won't do that.

[image]

You also see that "some settings are hidden or managed by [my] organization".

`w32tm /query /configuration` shows me that some policy sets time time source `Type` to `NT5DS`:

```
[Configuration]

EventLogFlags: 2 (Local)
AnnounceFlags: 10 (Local)
TimeJumpAuditOffset: 28800 (Local)
MinPollInterval: 10 (Local)
MaxPollInterval: 15 (Local)
MaxNegPhaseCorrection: 4294967295 (Local)
MaxPosPhaseCorrection: 4294967295 (Local)
MaxAllowedPhaseOffset: 300 (Local)

FrequencyCorrectRate: 4 (Local)
PollAdjustFactor: 5 (Local)
LargePhaseOffset: 50000000 (Local)
SpikeWatchPeriod: 900 (Local)
LocalClockDispersion: 10 (Local)
HoldPeriod: 5 (Local)
PhaseCorrectRate: 1 (Local)
UpdateInterval: 30000 (Local)

FileLogName: D:\time.log (Local)
FileLogEntries: 0-300 (Local)
FileLogSize: 1000000 (Local)

[TimeProviders]

NtpServer (Local)
DllName: C:\WINDOWS\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Policy)
InputProvider: 0 (Local)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)

NtpClient (Local)
DllName: C:\WINDOWS\system32\w32time.dll (Local)
Enabled: 1 (Local)
InputProvider: 1 (Local)
CrossSiteSyncFlags: 2 (Policy)
AllowNonstandardModeCombinations: 1 (Local)
ResolvePeerBackoffMinutes: 15 (Policy)
ResolvePeerBackoffMaxTimes: 7 (Policy)
CompatibilityFlags: 2147483648 (Local)
EventLogFlags: 0 (Policy)
LargeSampleSkew: 3 (Local)
SpecialPollInterval: 3600 (Policy)
Type: NT5DS (Policy)
```

My question is: where can I see where these things are set? I cannot seem to find anything in `rsop.msc` (anything I check there is "Not defined") or `gpresult.exe`.

How can I see where these settings are set so I can figure out if I can override them?

Comment: Domain clients have to synch to the domain controller.

Comment: This mark as a duplicate is incorrect. The other question is for non-domain joined systems, while my system *is* domain-joined. (And I tried the solution without success.)

Comment: In the particular question of NTP vs. NT5DS, I found `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\W32time` which I could rename to remove the NT5DS setting. This does not answer the question, however, because "Some of these settings ..." still appears, even after a reboot.

Comment: Security **requires** clients and servers agree on the time. Clients take their time from their domain servers. Anything else is a risk.

Comment: @user1292580 I agree with your 1st sentence. The 2nd does not apply: I cannot contact the domain servers for weeks at a time. So following your logic, security *requires* me to get a reliable time from some place else, wouldn't you agree?